# PYSMB missing when already installed

Tags: python

Im trying to run a program and I get the error message

```
You need to install pysmb
pip install pysmb
ERROR:root:pysmb missing
```

I do

```
pip3 install pysmb
```

and also suggested here in a diferent post  the installation with

```
pip2.7 install pysmb
```

with this last giving the error

```
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
Collecting pysmb
  Using cached pysmb-1.2.7.zip (1.3 MB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-lLiHMf/pysmb/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-lLiHMf/pysmb/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-USW4PM
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-lLiHMf/pysmb/
    Complete output (8 lines):
    /usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'install_requires'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
       or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
       or: setup.py --help-commands
       or: setup.py cmd --help
    
    error: invalid command 'egg_info'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I manage to successful install with pip install pysmb but when I try to run the program it keeps saying

You need to install pysmb

```
pip install pysmb
ERROR:root:pysmb missing
```

when I get also

```
Requirement already satisfied: pysmb in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (1.2.7)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from pysmb) (0.4.8)
```

How can I fix this?

EDIT:

trying to install pysmb three diferent ways

```
┌──(rootkali)-[~]
└─# pip3 install pysmb
Requirement already satisfied: pysmb in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (1.2.7)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from pysmb) (0.4.8)
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
┌──(rootkali)-[~]
└─# pip2.7 install pysmb
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
Collecting pysmb
  Using cached pysmb-1.2.7.zip (1.3 MB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-1eaRAy/pysmb/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-1eaRAy/pysmb/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-L4CJ2C
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-1eaRAy/pysmb/
    Complete output (8 lines):
    /usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'install_requires'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
       or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
       or: setup.py --help-commands
       or: setup.py cmd --help
    
    error: invalid command 'egg_info'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
┌──(rootkali)-[~]
└─# pip install pysmb                                                                                                                                                                                                                  1 ⨯
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
Collecting pysmb
  Using cached pysmb-1.2.7.zip (1.3 MB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-8zLzuI/pysmb/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-8zLzuI/pysmb/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-6Zi3wo
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-8zLzuI/pysmb/
    Complete output (8 lines):
    /usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'install_requires'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
       or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
       or: setup.py --help-commands
       or: setup.py cmd --help
    
    error: invalid command 'egg_info'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

EDIT 2:

import sys; sys.executable output

```
┌──(rootkali)-[~/Desktop]
└─# python sys.executable.py
/usr/bin/python
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
┌──(rootkali)-[~/Desktop]
└─# python3 sys.executable.py
/usr/bin/python3
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
┌──(rootkali)-[~/Desktop]
└─# python2.7 sys.executable.py
/usr/local/bin/python2.7
```

Comment: can you check if you have installed your package in same Python interpreter from which you are trying to run the code. Looks like your pysmb is installed for your Python3.9 not sure how and where you are running your code.

Comment: @Prayalankar Ashutosh I have edit my question with how Itried to install pysmb. I'm trying to run the code with python (not python (not python3). About where I'm running it, what do you need to know?

Comment: import sys; sys.executable; where ever you are running your code at same place run above code and it will tell. your python interpreter path . check if its matching with your installation path i.e usr/local/lib/python3.9/

Comment: the interpreter path is /usr/bin/python and the installation path is /root/redsnarf/
I dont know now what should I do in order to correct it